# Why is there a layout preview difference between Pixel and Pixel 2 in Android Studio even though they have same screen size and pixel density

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-emulator, google-pixel

I have been trying to understand why these two devices even though having same screen size and pixel density behave differently.

Please Note: The Font size and Display size are set to "Default" on both the devices.

**EDIT 1:** I have created the following folders in the layout folder.
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
layout-xxxhdpi

Each folder has the activity's layout with the dimension and image size fixed. My point is, if the two mobiles are using xxhdpi layouts or the Google Pixel is using xxxhdpi and Google Pixel 2 is using xxhdpi?

[image: App Preview on Google Pixel 2 Emulator]

[image: App Preview on Google Pixel Emulator]

Comment: You have to make different dimension(dimens.xml) for different layout .

Comment: I think there is a slight difference in Screen-to-body ratio
67.92 % for  Pixel 2 and 68.88 % for Pixel. Also when you created emulator did you noticed Pixel 2 is 420dpi and Pixel is xxhdpi, so there is a difference in dpi.

Comment: You should not spend time with this. I'm pretty sure that @sunilsunnywas right in his comment about what is the cause of problem. Having different displays on two different devices, it's expected to have different layouts in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on DPI of your phone. Two phones may have different dpi. You can change dpi if phone is rooted. I dont know if stock supports.

Comment: So can you suggest on how should I declare the layout files so that it looks same on both the devices? I am confused!

Answer (score 0):

**Please Note: The Font size and Display size are set to "Default" on both the devices.**

No , You have to using dimens.xml for different devices of android for Example see Below structure :

```
res/values/dimens.xml

res/values-small/dimens.xml

res/values-normal/dimens.xml

res/values-large/dimens.xml

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

**dimens.xml file contains**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In Textview add this

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
```

Comment: Put different size in different dimens.xml file.

Comment: This is wrong. You don't have to use any dimens to set the size of a `TextView` to default.

Comment: I give her answer with no. I highlight his question and then say no. Please read.

Comment: Also I explained that we should define font size as per layout .

Comment: The second part of your answer is not useful here since it covers another topic. I'm not really sure that I understand what you want to say, but the user simply said that it uses the default sizes inside the app, but the output is different. So, for what exactly is that "no"?

Comment: OK , I removed second part .